# Smooth Scroll with Keyboard Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling, jquery-waypoints

I'm looking to try and add some keyboard navigation using the Waypoints and Stellar jQuery Plugins. I have my smooth scroll all setup so that when you click the link it takes you to the appropriate data-slide position.

I'm trying to implement a keyboard nav so that when the up and down keys are pressed it takes you to the next or previous data slide. I thought I was on the right track, but doesn't seem to be coming together.

It looks like I am getting the keydown function to work appropriately, but just not the scroll to the respective data-slide position.

Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thanks!

**Waypoint/Smooth Scroll Nav**

```
slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }

});

mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }
});

function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
}

links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);

});
```

**My Code for Keyboard Nav:**

```
 mywindow.keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 40) { //DOWN
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Down Arrow Has Been Pressed');
        goToByScroll();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //UP
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Up Arrow Has Been Pressed');
        goToByScroll();
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling your `goToByScroll` function with an argument when you use the keyboard navigation - it looks like that's why it's not working. You'll need to keep track of your active dataslide so that you can pass that variable to your `goToByScroll` function in your keyhandlers.

It'd look something like this (this is really crude):

```
var currentDataSlide = 0;

function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');

    currentDataSlide = dataslide;
}
mywindow.keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 40) { //DOWN
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Down Arrow Has Been Pressed');
        goToByScroll(currentDataSlide + 1);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //UP
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Up Arrow Has Been Pressed');
        goToByScroll(currentDataSlide - 1);
    }       
});
```

That's not perfect, but the idea is to keep track of where you are (slide-wise) and pass that variable when you use your keyhandlers.

Comment: That was my concern as well. Was keeping track of the current dataslide. Isn't thats whats going on here: 

    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

Is there a way to pass the "Next" or "Previous" slide?

Comment: if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }

So for example, they are using a next or prev function to determine which slide to apple the active state too. Wouldn't the same principle apply to passing the next and previous slide. But how do we pass that into the scroll function?

Comment: If that's the case and dataslide is your tracking variable, then look at your keyboard handler - pass `dataslide` to your scroll function in the keyhandler. You're not passing anything there - you're just calling gotobyscroll() without the required argument.

Comment: I realize I needed to pass an argument, but I didn't think that dataslide was the right argument. I updated the code to pass dataslide + 1 and dataslide - 1 for next and previous. Its not really acting quite right. If you are at the beginning of the slide and press the down key. It fires, you get the alert message, but doesn't move the slide down. If you are in the middle of the current slide, and press the up or down key. It scrolls to the top of that current slide your in. 

Here is a link to see a live preview. Obviously this is still in development. http://myedencreative.com/vantage_point/

Comment: Now that I've seen your full code, the answer is no - `dataslide` is set inside your waypoint handler, ad I don't know anything about that library. Try adding var `currentSlide = 0` near your other declarations after your `document.ready` statement, and use currentSlide in your arguments.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I went with your suggestion on setting a different variable. From there, all I had to do was increment the slide position based if i was going up or down. Appreciate you taking the time and giving some direction!